# Date not being displayed properly when using jQuery mask

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use [this jQuery plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) as an input mask on my ASP MVC `edit` page. However, no matter what the value is being stored in the database, the month is always displayed with two zeros: `00/dd/yyyy`. I've stepped through the code in Visual Studio and checked the actual value stored in the database and have verified that it is correct.

Here is the jQuery from the view. All of the other input masks work properly on this page. `$('#Birthdate')` is the one in question.

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#HomePhone').mask("(999) 999-9999? x99999");
    $('#BusinessPhone').mask("(999) 999-9999? x99999");
    $('#MobilePhone').mask("(999) 999-9999");
    $('#FaxNumber').mask("(999) 999-9999? x99999");
    $('#Birthdate').mask("99/99/9999");
    $('#HomeZip').mask("99999?-9999");
    $('#MailingZip').mask("99999?-9999");
    $('#LocationZip').mask("99999?-9999");
});

    <div class="M-editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Birthdate)
    </div>
    <div class="M-validator-field">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Birthdate)
    </div>
```

Here is the jquery that I am using on the page.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

Here is the field on the model. I have the display set as such

```
    [DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:mm/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be an issue w/the `DisplayFormat`'s `DataFormatString`. Capitalizing the month fixed the problem :)

```
    [DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
```